# Server 2008 - Windows Server Backup to specific folder? file level backup

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-backup

When I run Windows Server Backup, custom, files and folders, then in the Destination selection, there is only Volume and Share??? Why is this?
Why am I forced to use the root level of my local secondary drive to backup files and folders?
I know there are other programs to do file level backups, even free ones, but I need something that will backup files that are 'in use' for specific reasons.
so my question, how can I select a specific folder as the destination?

Comment: Create a shared folder on your backup drive. Select that shared folder (via UNC path) as the backup destination.

Comment: Bear in mind that doing what @joeqwerty suggests will limit you to keeping a single generation of backup (because VSS isn't supported on UNC-based destinations).

Comment: My bad. I glossed over the `in use` part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Evan Anderson's comment says, Windows Server backup uses VSS to store backups unless it's writing to a network share.  This is why your backup storage disk is hidden from Windows explorer (and you, unless you're using specialized tools):  VSS wants to choose where to write the backups.

Because VSS isn't supported on UNC destinations, you'll only be able to keep a single backup if you back up to a share.

Other possible issues include (C&Ped from [Microsoft's docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753528.aspx)):

> - If you are using a virtual hard disk to store backups and if the    virtual hard disk is on a physical disk that contains system volumes
>     or critical volumes, there may be limitations to what you can
>     recover. In addition, virtual volume files will be excluded from the
>     backup if the virtual volumes are online. For more information about
>     working with virtual hard disks, see
>     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=143712.
> - If you are using a dynamic disk instead of a basic disk to store    backups, you will not be able to perform bare metal recoveries with
>     backups stored on the dynamic disk. However, you will be able to
>     perform other types of recoveries. For more information about using
>     dynamic disks, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=143750.

I'd recommend using a specific disk solely for backups.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  in this case I just want to backup a local folder on drive c: ('in use files') and put them anywhere on my local server , then back them up using backupassist to a remote location.

Comment: Also to add, I still don't understand why the destination folder is not s electable. especially if it's on a separate partition.

Comment: VSS doesn't store snapshots in "normal" NTFS locations.  Windows Server Backup uses VSS snapshots to store backups.  You cannot choose where to store a VSS snapshot.  If you choose to store your backup on a network share, you may only store one copy because Windows Server Backup cannot store multiple copies in a network share because it cannot use VSS on a share.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I'm just curious why they chose to do it this way.   Windows Server Backup creates the snapshot of the selected folders, I use another third party program to move those backups elsewhere.  This should be doable with one step but I guess MS chose not do.

Comment: Yeah, I assume they assume you're going to use their product, period.  If you feel like other people would benefit from the feature you can always [suggest it](https://connect.microsoft.com/), but I don't imagine it'll be a high priority.